# Windows forms problem

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

when I create an application with a form X I use: `X->Show();` The application terminates instantly. So I use the `X->ShowDialog();` method. Now the UI stops to execute anything after that line. Message boxes will only be shown after I closed the form X, updates and textbox changes won't result in anything...??? How to get rid of this problem? I only want to show a form and change some content of it by user interactions and the user should close it(not the program)...shouldn't it be the easiest thing all over the world when I'm programming Windows programs for Windows with Windows forms? LOL!

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1^ X = gcnew Form1();

    X->ShowDialog();
    MessageBox::Show("test", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
    // message box not shown, only after closing the form...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: X->Show() is not valid syntax for a Form class named X.  Post code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: push...7 billion people on earth knowing Windows and nobody can answer easy questions. And I can't do it in my own...else I wouldn't ask lol

Comment: Make up your mind, do you want `main` to continue (with the `MessageBox` and then exiting the program) or do you want the program to stay running until the Form exits?  You can't have both.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about **c++-cli** right now but in **C#** the main form is started and shown in this way:

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

so I can be wrong here, but where is your `Application.Run` ?

Comment: Correct, a message loop is needed, and `Application::Run` is the WinForms standard message loop.

Comment: With this message loop I have the same result. My message box isn't displayed until I close my form. I don't want to close it. I want to see the message box over the form.

Comment: @hmm : The latest code you've shown here does _not_ use the standard message loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is illogical.  You can either ShowDialog() which keeps your program running until the form is closed, *or* you can keep going through the program and exit immediately.  Where do you expect your program to pause? And when do you expect it to close?

The simplest 'solution' to get both on the screen is to reverse the order to:

```
MessageBox::Show("test", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
X->ShowDialog();
```

then you'll get both on screen.  Otherwise run the MessageBox from within the form (in the constructor, OnLoad, wherever).